# How to optimize pandas column calculation which uses previous value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, optimization

Each row uses the computed value of previous value . For loop is hitting the performance of program . Is there a better approach to improve the performance.

I have the following dataframe:

```
       close      basic_lb      basic_ub  final_lb  final_ub
0   18801.70  18823.800000  18823.800000       0.0       0.0
1   18794.65  18750.575000  18845.675000       0.0       0.0
2   18827.30  18758.725000  18864.925000       0.0       0.0
3   18862.10  18786.850000  18904.450000       0.0       0.0
4   18849.25  18794.340000  18911.310000       0.0       0.0
5   18850.70  18791.143500  18903.556500       0.0       0.0
6   18859.65  18798.624150  18907.625850       0.0       0.0
7   18840.80  18795.519235  18904.930765       0.0       0.0
8   18831.95  18782.764812  18887.835188       0.0       0.0
9   18847.00  18787.678330  18891.271670       0.0       0.0
10  18815.00  18772.292997  18888.957003       0.0       0.0
11  18812.30  18759.911198  18870.938802       0.0       0.0
12  18816.95  18752.947578  18863.402422       0.0       0.0
13  18817.60  18762.375320  18869.674680       0.0       0.0
14  18815.15  18764.835288  18864.914712       0.0       0.0
```

The below is the for loop which need to be updated (data is the dataFrame) :

```
for i in range(1, len(data)):
            data['final_ub'].iat[i] = data['basic_ub'].iat[i] if data['basic_ub'].iat[i] < data['final_ub'].iat[i - 1] or data['close'].iat[i - 1] > data['final_ub'].iat[i - 1] else data['final_ub'].iat[i - 1]
            data['final_lb'].iat[i] = data['basic_lb'].iat[i] if data['basic_lb'].iat[i] > data['final_lb'].iat[i - 1] or data['close'].iat[i - 1] < data['final_lb'].iat[i - 1] else data['final_lb'].iat[i - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to vectorize this task with just pandas/numpy functions (because you have dependent variables).

But this is the task where [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) JIT shines, so you can convert this function to:

```py
from numba import njit


@njit
def fn(close_vals, basic_lb_vals, basic_ub_vals, final_lb, final_ub):
    for i in range(1, len(close_vals)):
        final_ub[i] = (
            basic_ub_vals[i]
            if basic_ub_vals[i] < final_ub[i - 1] or close_vals[i - 1] > final_ub[i - 1]
            else final_ub[i - 1]
        )

        final_lb[i] = (
            basic_lb_vals[i]
            if basic_lb_vals[i] > final_lb[i - 1] or close_vals[i - 1] < final_lb[i - 1]
            else final_lb[i - 1]
        )

data["final_lb"] = 0.0
data["final_ub"] = 0.0

fn(
    data["close"].values,
    data["basic_lb"].values,
    data["basic_ub"].values,
    data["final_lb"].values,
    data["final_ub"].values,
)
```

---

Quick benchmark with dataframe of 150_000 rows:

```py
from timeit import timeit


@njit
def fn(close_vals, basic_lb_vals, basic_ub_vals, final_lb, final_ub):
    for i in range(1, len(close_vals)):
        final_ub[i] = (
            basic_ub_vals[i]
            if basic_ub_vals[i] < final_ub[i - 1] or close_vals[i - 1] > final_ub[i - 1]
            else final_ub[i - 1]
        )

        final_lb[i] = (
            basic_lb_vals[i]
            if basic_lb_vals[i] > final_lb[i - 1] or close_vals[i - 1] < final_lb[i - 1]
            else final_lb[i - 1]
        )


def fn_normal(data):
    data["final_lb"] = 0.0
    data["final_ub"] = 0.0

    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        data["final_ub"].iat[i] = (
            data["basic_ub"].iat[i]
            if data["basic_ub"].iat[i] < data["final_ub"].iat[i - 1]
            or data["close"].iat[i - 1] > data["final_ub"].iat[i - 1]
            else data["final_ub"].iat[i - 1]
        )
        data["final_lb"].iat[i] = (
            data["basic_lb"].iat[i]
            if data["basic_lb"].iat[i] > data["final_lb"].iat[i - 1]
            or data["close"].iat[i - 1] < data["final_lb"].iat[i - 1]
            else data["final_lb"].iat[i - 1]
        )

    return data


def fn_numba(data):
    data["final_lb"] = 0.0
    data["final_ub"] = 0.0

    fn(
        data["close"].values,
        data["basic_lb"].values,
        data["basic_ub"].values,
        data["final_lb"].values,
        data["final_ub"].values,
    )

    return data

t1 = timeit(
    "fn_normal(x)", setup="x=pd.concat([data]*10_000)", number=1, globals=globals()
)

# "warm" the jit with some small data
fn_numba(data)

t2 = timeit(
    "fn_numba(x)", setup="x=pd.concat([data]*10_000)", number=1, globals=globals()
)

print("fn_normal =", t1)
print("fn_numba =", t2)
```

Prints on my computer (AMD 5700x):

```
fn_normal = 10.814594153081998
fn_numba = 0.00066734803840518
```

Answer (score -1):

Explore the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function and use it to update your required columns. This will be faster than writing a for loop.

(Updated as per comment)
I'm not exactly sure what you're doing in your if statement, but you can use something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.rand(10), 'col2': np.random.rand(10)})
# lagged column
df['lag1'] =df['col1'].shift(1) 
# similar to your if statement (though there might be an efficient way to do the same)
df['newcol1'] = (df['lag1'] > df['col2']).astype(int) * df['col1'] + (df['lag1'] <= df['col2']).astype(int) *df['col2']
```

Hopefully this answers your question

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on how to use shift in this case , because the resulting column need to be shifted before computation.